$\Delta U = U - U$ elementwise = $2R$ for every UFD $R$ and its group of units $U$. Or there is some formula...

Conjecture. Every group of units $U = \Bbb{Z}/n^{\times}$ of the ring $R = \Bbb{Z}/n$, has an elementwise difference set $\Delta U$ equaling:
$$
\Delta U = U - U = \{ u - v : u,v \in U\} = 2R
$$

I reason this way: decompose $n$ into $p_i^{k_i}$ powers.  By induction suppose that it's true for all $1 \leq k \lt n$.  Then it's true for all $R_i' = \Bbb{Z}/p_i^{k_i}$.  This means:
$U_i' = R_i'^{\times}$ and $\Delta U_i' = 2R_i'$.  Now, the set of units $U$ of the ring $R$ is isomorphic to the product of each of the $U'_i$ as $i$ varies with $i \in I =$ the set of all indicies $i$ of primes $p_i$ dividing $n$. That is:
$$
U \simeq \prod_{i \in } U_i'
$$
Question. Does this mean as well that $\Delta U \simeq \prod_{i\in } \Delta U_i$ as sets?
If so then $\Delta U = \rho(\prod_{i\in I}  2R_i) = 2R$ where $\rho$ is the CRT isomorphism.

What is $u-v$ in the multiplicative group $U$? Do you mean $uv^{-1}$?

@DietrichBurde no, it's difference in the ring $\Bbb{Z}/n$.

For $n=8$ we have $U(8)={1,3,5,7}$. So $u-v$ in the ring $R=\Bbb Z/8$ cannot be odd. I don't understand, how it should be $R$.

@DietrichBurde the rule then is if $2 \mid n$, it's $2R$ whereas if $2\nmid n$, it is equal to the whole ring.  Two being a special case, for some reason...

The induction hypothesis does not apply in the case that $n$ is a prime power, so this case requires a separate argument. However it seems that this case is relatively easy.

Also, I don't see why the votes to close?  I obviously put some effort into answering this, that was everything after "I reason as follows..." which in turn brought up a nice on-topic, specific question.  So whoever is out there constantly close-voting me, please do some original mathematical thought on your own, and then tell me this is a closeable post.


Does this mean as well that $\Delta U \simeq \prod_{i\in I} \Delta U_i'$ as sets?

Yes. It helps to think about elements of $U \simeq \prod_{i\in I} U_i'$ as vectors of length $|I|$ with ordinary vector addition/subtraction.
We need to show two things:

Every difference between two such vectors is a vector where each entry is the difference of two elements in the corresponding $U_i'$.
Every vector where each entry is the difference of two elements in the $U_i'$ corresponding to that row can be written as the difference between two vectors in $\prod_{i\in I} U_i'$

Both are completely obvious. Any proof would be nothing more then repeating the definition of vector addition.
Of course we need to realize is that the thing that makes this obvious is that the CRT morphism does indeed send the ordinary addition in $R$ to the vector addition in $\prod R_i'$. Perhaps you should try and write a proof of this fact, but it is a standard part of the CRT.
PS as I stated in the comments: for the full result you need to write a separate argument for the case that $R = R_1'$, i.e. $n = p^k$ for some $p$ and $k$ since your induction argument doesn't apply there.

I like your proof but you didn't mention anything about uniqueness, such as $u - v\in R; u,v \in U$ corresponds to a unique tuple of differences of units.  Don't we need this for bijection, why or why not?  Or did you somehow demonstrate two maps that are inverse to one another, because I know that would work as well.

also what can be said for either $n \in \Bbb{N}$ or square-free $n \in \Bbb{N}$?  I.e. does a pattern emerge or is it too chaotic to tell.  Re: my comment above about when $2R$ occurs or if $R$ occurs. I'm not sure if I have it correct and it's probably not correct, so... your answer may be augmented if you're up for it.  Thanks!  As the explicit goal was that question that you answered, but implicitly the post is also about the stated conjecture, which your answer as a lemma, helps to prove.
